# $.post / $.ajax code complete after timeout but still execute call from server

Tags: jquery, post

I created a series of $.post in sequence wherein the next $.post is loaded as callback when the load is completed.

```
 $.post("test", function() {
      alert("success");
    })
    .complete(function() { 
         //LOAD NEXT SEQUENCE OF POST HERE
    });
```

My problem is that what if my first sequence loads in 2mins, then I need to wait for 2 mins for the next post. What I want to do is the even though the lst sequence is not yet complete, after five seconds, the next load will be executed. I've read about the $.ajax timeout but I don't want it to stop executing the call from the server.... I just want to make sure that the next sequence will be loaded after a timeout of 5 secs.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just run it using a setinterval?

Comment: If i put it inside the $post.. will it still wait for the server to finish executing the loading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setInterval function

```
function Yourfunction()
{
    //here you need to do post one after other 
    $.post("test", function() {
      alert("success");
    }).complete(function() { 
     //Here if your interval is not elapsed and completed triggered then your next post will be loaded.
     //LOAD NEXT SEQUENCE OF POST HERE/ 
    });
}
setInterval(Yourfunction, 5000);
```

Comment: I'm confused... Yourfunction does it mean that the $post function?

Comment: But my next load of function is inside the $post itself

Comment: I have 10 sequence of $post... and i load the next one inside the $.post complete...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap the method in a setTimeout and call it when you want to start the next attempt.

```
var timer;
function attemptNext()
{
    timer = setTimeout(tryPost, 5000);
}

function tryPost()
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
    attemptNext('MY URL');
    $.post("test", function() {
        alert("success");
    })
    .complete(function() { 
        tryPost();
    });
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it still wait for the $.post to finish before it calls the function attemptNext() ?

Comment: Sorry, posted prematurely. Updated.